# Changing html on a view based on if get parameter is set on Codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, get, view

Before I used Codeigniter I had a page show certain html as long as the url had no get parameters and then have some of the html be replaced by another as soon as something like this is set in the url:

```
localhost/signup.php?success
```

Now my question is, what is the best way to do this in Codeigniter? Would I have to use one of those parameters on the controller's function (which I still can't get my head around)? And if so, how? Or if I just had php logic in the view like I used to do in plain PHP, what would I check for if not a get parameter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many ways to achieve this certain thing.

- routes.php
- [extending controller](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) and using constructor so you apply rules for every extended controller
- [flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Before you start please read up on frameworks watch some [video tutorials](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/codeigniter-from-scratch--net-17602) on how to make simple blog system etc. I myself wouldn't just jump in to concept, study up.

I mentioned flashdata and that is how you do things done (success, alert, warning bars).

Answer (score 1):

By default, GET parameters are not enabled or useful in codeigniter, but URI segments work the same way. So...

If you had a controller called, signup.php and a function inside it called success, you could link to that with:

localhost/signup/success

then if you loaded the URL helper, which I always do in config/autoload.php or just with:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

You could say:

```
if($this->uri->segment(2) == 'success') {
     //Show success message or load a view for it...
}else {
     //The second URI segment is NOT 'success' so do something else...
}
```

But... codeigniter is just a framework for PHP. If it's possible in PHP, it's possible in codeigniter. You can simply go into the config/config.php file and enable query strings, but I would strongly suggest using URI segments and reading up on them as well as the URL helper.